# Spring-boot application logs eating up the space in mounted location in docker

Tags: linux, spring-boot, docker, logging

Im running a docker container (springboot application running inside) with mounting a location for the logs.

```
docker run -d --name myContainer 8080:80 -v /server/appLogs:/var/log myContainer:latest
```

Here im mounting `/server/appLogs` to the location `/var/log/`. my spring boot application logs are written inside the `/var/log` location and I need to take logs out to the host machine.

But with the time log are getting collected inside `/server/appLogs` location and its filling all my space in the server.
I know from logback-spring.xml file we can handle the max size and max history but those settings doesnt applies for the mounted location.

I have a plan to write a shell script and add a cron job for auto deleting the logs in the location.
Is there any other good method to clear the logs in this `/server/appLogs` location?
why the configurations in logback-spring.xml doesn't get applies here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ELK (https://www.elastic.co/) for application logs.
this is the complete guide for your ref: https://logz.io/learn/complete-guide-elk-stack/#elasticsearch

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).